# FBLoginView iPhone View

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, ios6

Using the FBLoginView in the current 3.1 Facebook SDK doesn't produce what I believe it should be producing as an output.  Generating a basic [[FBLoginView alloc] init]; and the frame the size of the current view controllers frame, it only shows the below WITHOUT the "Login" button:

http://cl.ly/image/1t102j1t452l

What does it take to make the FBLoginView show properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

In .h file:

```
Use this delegate <FBLoginViewDelegate>

FBLoginView *loginview;
```

In.m file in someMethod:

```
if(!loginView)
 loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions, user_photos,status_update"]]; // Whatever permissions you need

loginview.frame = self.view.bounds; //whatever you want

loginview.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:loginview];
```

Add these methods:

```
- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {

    NSLog(@"Logged In");

}

- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {
NSLog(@"user Id %@",user.id);

}
- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
    // Called after logout
    NSLog(@"Logged out");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Still does not appear to be working.  Same outcome on this one as the screenshot I posted.

Comment: It appears I got a version of it working, except I had to manually add the Facebook logo image and login button to the view myself - not quite sure that's how it's suppose to work though.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that I was missing **FacebookSDKResources.bundle** in my project. When I added it, it started working.