# Login issue in facebook integration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, ios6

I have integrated facebook in ios 6 successfully but i noticed a strange behaviour of the app. 
Whenever i try to login using facebook everything works fine but when any other user with his/her credentials tries to login, an error shows up. I don't know what's the solution for it.

i am using facebook sdk sample code as reference. For login i am just setting the view frame for login. The protocol implementation for FBLoginView is as follows:

```
- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView
{
BOOL canShareAnyhow = [FBNativeDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithSession:nil];
// first get the buttons set for login mode
self.postStatusBtn.enabled = YES;
self.shareWithFriendsBtn.enabled = YES;
self.viewFriends.enabled = YES;

}

- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                        user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
{
// here we use helper properties of FBGraphUser to dot-through to first_name and
// id properties of the json response from the server; alternatively we could use
// NSDictionary methods such as objectForKey to get values from the my json object

// setting the profileID property of the FBProfilePictureView instance
// causes the control to fetch and display the profile picture for the user


self.profilePic.profileID = user.id;
self.loggedInUser = user;
NSLog(@"%@",user);

}

- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView
{
BOOL canShareAnyhow = [FBNativeDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithSession:nil];

self.postStatusBtn.enabled = NO;
self.shareWithFriendsBtn.enabled = NO;
self.viewFriends.enabled = NO;
if (!self.viewFriends.enabled)
{
    self.viewFriends.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
}

if(!self.shareWithFriendsBtn.enabled)
{
    self.shareWithFriendsBtn.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
}

if (!self.postStatusBtn.enabled)
{
    self.postStatusBtn.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
}

self.profilePic.profileID = nil;

self.loggedInUser = nil;
}
```

Thanx in advance...!!

Comment: Could be the permissions, post your FBLoginView code here, then we will be able to help you more.

Comment: Please post some code or post error :)

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: @jattt.... it just shows the error with the message 'an error occured. Please try again later' and clicking 'Okay' returns d control to the app.

Comment: @daemon22 Pls check my answer I just posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will fix your issue:

1. Go to you Facebook app in your Facebook account.
2. Click edit your app.
3. Go to Basic info tab.
4. **Sandbox Mode:**  **check this as Disable**
5. Save the setting.

This will work for you.

Comment: @jatt i did not get the edit and sandbox option on facebook developer

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to clear the token when user logs out and someone else login? Following one liner you need to put in where you are logging out the user or user is pressing logout button:

```
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Delete the bulid, clean all targets, and then run the build again and add above line in the logout button.

Comment: Oh well then there might be something else needs to be fixed.

Comment: do i need to request for more permissions???
i guess it should work using basic permissions only...

Comment: No, if you are able to login once and then logout clearly and then trying to login and it is creating issues there. If this is the actual issue then it has to be regarding clearing out the cache and token etc.

Comment: Well not really is that case. Actually i created the app and generated app id from my fb account and app works fine only when we login through those credentials only. Otherwise it shows error.

Comment: Strange, Try to create a new appid and then use it (try creating it from other account) and then use it in your application.

Comment: if problem remains the same then it has to be your code that's not working for you. :)

Comment: yep it could be the case too...!!

Comment: d problem is with my code only....!!
cn u help me out on how should i use facebook sdk 3.1 in ios???
thnx fr ur help....

Comment: Try this post of mine - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243640/fbloginview-iphone-view/14244103#14244103 Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Also I am assuming you are adding entry into the plist file of the application. I am talking about FBAppID. :)

Comment: Cool, tried the code I have posted here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243640/fbloginview-iphone-view/14244103#14244103 ?

Comment: God forbids, If you are not down with this yet, then I have the last shot for you and this is the one - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/ Peace!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
-(IBAction) loginFrmFbBtnPressed:(id)sender
{
    if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
    {
        [self getData];
    } else
    {
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                                                                 FBSessionState status, NSError *error)
         {
             if (error)
             {
                 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:error.localizedDescription delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                 [alert show];
             }
             else if (FB_ISSESSIONOPENWITHSTATE(status))
             {
                 [self getData];
             }
         }];
    }
}

-(void)getData
{
    if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"read_stream"] == NSNotFound)
    {
        NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                @"read_stream" , nil];
        [FBSession.activeSession reauthorizeWithReadPermissions:permissions completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                [self request];
            }
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        [self request];
    }
}

-(void)request
{
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"picture,id,birthday,email,name,gender,username" forKey:@"fields"] HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
     {
         [self meRequestResult:result WithError:error];
     }];
}

- (void)meRequestResult:(id)result WithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        NSDictionary *dictionary;
        if([result objectForKey:@"data"])
            dictionary = (NSDictionary *)[(NSArray *)[result objectForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:0];
        else
            dictionary = (NSDictionary *)result;
        NSLog(@"dictionary : %@",dictionary);
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: thnx fr d code but i am using facebook sdk sample code as reference.
It would be gr8 if u could help me with that...